# Locate files relating to MS Security Essentials scan result

Tags: windows-7, security

I just ran a MS Security Essentials scan on my computer. The results show two entries under "Allowed". I don't remember allowing any such items to run on my computer.

[image: MS Security Essentials Screenshot]

How can I locate the files related to these entries so I can decide on further action?

Comment: You can't locate them;  The lack of a filename makes it impossible to determine what the actual file was.  If you are worried just have MSE remove the files.

Comment: It looks like you could just remove the items from the whitelist and do a re-scan - then MSE should tell you where they're detected during the rescan, if they're still actually on the system at all.